# Autologin google, redirection webview not working

Tags: android, redirect, webview

In Android i have a `webview` that lead to an google authentication form. When the authentication form is loaded in the webview it will call `onReceivedLoginRequest`:

```
public void onReceivedLoginRequest(final AuthenticationWebView client, final WebView view, final String realm,
        final String account, final String args) {
    ...
}
```

When this method is called i get the `Accounts` stored on the device and let the user choose one and use that one to retrieve an authtoken:

```
mAccountManager.getAuthToken(account, mAuthToken, null, mWebViewActivity, this, null);
```

It all works perfectly fine (i think) and the next step looks good also:

```
final String result = bundle.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
        if (result != null) {
            // authentication succeeded, new url given as result for redirection
            mWebView.loadUrl(result);
        } else {
            onLoginFailed();
        }
```

A new method is called and returns the new url for redirection which i load in the webview. The result String returns a new adress which looks good but does nothing, it doens't log in but i don't get any message error either from the webview.

Url:

`https://accounts.google.com/MergeSession?args=..&uberauth=WILL_NOT_SIGN_IN&source=AndroidWebLogin`

I modified the url a bit with (triple)dots, don't know how secure it is and it was not such an interesting part of the url.

Anyone know why the url will not redirect me to the website behind it? When i use this url in my browser it `recognizes` my account, i only have to fill in my password and it redirects me `correctly`.

I use a `native Android webview` and i inject it with javascript but this only happens on the page after the login.
The settings i added to the webview are:

```
mSettings = getSettings();
mSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
mSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
```